# How to add Windows Media Player to Toolbox

Tags: asp.net, media-player, toolbox

I am doing asp.net web application that will play the media on the website.

I am trying to add Windows Media Player tools on Toolbox but when I try to add I have:

"The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer:

```
Windows Media Player
```

Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework version.
"

Comment: what version is your .net framework? and visual studio?

Comment: @Mohammad .net framework4.7.2 visual studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the latest version of the **Player** and the Player **SDK** is installed on your machine.
2. Install and register the **PIA**. For more information, see [Registering Primary Interop Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-register-primary-interop-assemblies) for Application Development.
3. Start a new project in Visual Studio .NET.
4. From the Tools menu, select Customize Toolbox.
5. In the COM Components tab, click on the check box for Windows Media Player item to select the Player. Click OK to close the dialog and add the Player to the Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your project, make sure you are using the right .NET Framework  version. Select the Windows Form app with the VB logo on the corner of it, and use .NET Framework 4.5. I'm running Visual Studio 2019 and it works fine for me.